# Typescript private setter public getter convention

Tags: javascript, typescript

So I want to have an immutable Vector class. For this I need to have a public getter for the x and y coordinates and a private setter so that I can actually initialize those values in the constructor.

I have a few options at my disposal so I'm wondering which one is per convention.

I could do it like this:

```
class Vector {
    constructor(private _x: number, private _y: number) { }
    public get x() {
        return this._x;
    }

    public get y() {
        return this._y;
    }
}
```

But I don't know if using an underscore is a common thing to do. This might be an issue since that name will be visible in the intellisense.

The second option could be

```
class Vector {
    constructor(private x: number, private y: number) { }
    public get X() {
        return this.x;
    }

    public get Y() {
        return this.y;
    }
}
```

As far as I know, only classes start with capitals in JS so this might also be a bad idea.

What is the preferred way to handle this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The general consensus so far has been to use the underscore. Private variables are not shown in auto-completion outside of the class - so you wouldn't see `_x` or `_y` in auto-completion on an instance of `Vector`. The only place you will see them is when calling the constructor and if that really offends, you can avoid auto-mapping (although I'd rather have the auto-mapping).

```
class Vector {
    private _x: number;
    private _y: number;

    constructor(x: number, y: number) { 
        this._x = x;
        this._y = y;
    }

    public get x() {
        return this._x;
    }

    public get y() {
        return this._y;
    }
}

var vector = new Vector(1, 2);
```

There is no official standard on this yet - but it is best to follow JavaScript style naming conventions if there is any chance whatsoever of interacting with external code as it will avoid switching conventions back and forth depending on whether you are calling a "Function We Made" or a "Function They Made".

Avoiding differences only in case is also a recommendation in Code Complete by Steve McConnell - which is another bad point against `x` and `X` along with the naming convention point you mentioned in the question.

Comment: Might want to add the `number` type to `x` and `y` property declarations.

Comment: No need - the awesome power of type inference knows they are numbers already.

Comment: Hmm .. I thought so too, but the Playground didn't infer them correctly (which I took to mean that the compiler hadn't either).

Comment: Sometimes the language service funks-out. If you copy your code out and reload the page it all sorts itself out.

Comment: The underscore is a convention in _Javascript_ because Javascript doesn't have private members. Typescript has though.

Comment: @freshfelicio as with all naming conventions in TypeScript, we prefer to use JavaScript conventions - because althogu *we* are writing TypeScript, people *may* be consuming the generated JavaScript.

Comment: The problem is that if you don't use the underscore, the private variable has the same name as the getter / setter. In C# this is solved by capitalizing the public getter / setter. Strangely, typescript convention advises you don't use the  _underscore.